# Old movie about an immortal man who saves a young girl

Tags: identify-this-movie

Ok, this is a long shot considering that I don't remember very much at all about this movie. I watched it with my parents like 10 years ago but I've always wondered what movie it was.

---

I only remember a small part of and the details are somewhat fuzzy but it's about a man who can't die. Full on immortality, doesn't age and can't get hurt (I think) but I have no idea if his immortality is explained. He saves a young girl and takes care of her, and then I think they get romatically invloled when she gets older (maybe they're even married). Eventually she grows old and she's lying on her (death?)bed, and they talk about his immortality and how he's watched many loved ones grow old and die.

And that's about all I can remember. I'm sure it was in English. I'd guess it was made somewhere inbetween 1980 and 1999. Also I'm pretty sure it doesn't take place in present day, at least not when any of this happens. Again, I'm not sure.

---

After some research I thought it might have been Highlander because the summary on wikipedia states that the character saves a young girl but The rest of the summary didn't seem to fit. I haven't watched it though, so I don't know for sure.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Country\language? Approximate year\decade?

Comment: I'm sure it was in english, as for when it was made, i have no clue. I'd guess somwhere in between 1980 and 1999. I was just a kid when I saw it so my ability to notice the age of a movie wasn't exactly at it's best.

Comment: I think it's Bicentennial Man with Robin Williams

Comment: Interview with a vampire?

Comment: My vote goes to Bicentennial Man, Robin Williams is an android who falls in love with the granddaughter of his first owner (have to check that) he later becomes almost human-like (think Pinocchio), and succeeds in marring his love. He is immortal.... but I think they die together. On the same deathbed. Oh, sorry Spoiler alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sure sounds like Highlander.  Is this it?

Comment: No, that's not it, I'm pretty sure it was an urban setting for the part I described. I'm trying to remember more details but it's all very fuzzy.

Comment: Connor and his secretary perhaps? Though they didn't really show they were romantically involved. Only implied.

Comment: @MadeleneJohansson, though this particular video may not match your memory, part of Highlander plays in a modern setting. Doug may just be right, I was thinking of this movie too.

Comment: @peopje Ok, that sounds promising. I'll try to get ahold of it so that I can check it out.

Comment: @MadeleneJohansson Since I know can comment, here is a link to the scene where he rescues the little girl interleaved with a scene where she's already old: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUUgywvbZOo&

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure it's Highlander.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Highlander is the movie you're after. He saves her from a Nazi and raises her as his daughter. He doesn't become romantically involved with the woman he raised though, it was instead a reporter who discovered his immortality. The majority of the first movie jumps back and forth between his memories and modern (1980's) New York.

While there is a deathbed scene in the first movie, the deathbed scene you mentioned though is in the second film where he recounts his life with the lead female of the first film to the new staring lady of the second film.

In all honesty, watch the first one and leave it at that, as most people would agree they go downhill from there. The first film is great though, and is perfect as a stand-alone film that doesn't need to be viewed as part of a series.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [New Amsterdam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Amsterdam_%28TV_series%29)? It's not an old movie but sounds similar.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't look familiar.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative candidate would be the Bicentennial Man

It's about a robot who develops a personality, fights for his freedom, leaves the family that originally bought him and later returns to fall in love and have a relationship with the family's grand-daughter, now an adult. She ages normally while he obviously doesn't. But later on he makes sure he can "die" as well and he dies with or shortly after her.
As a robot he is hard to harm and basically could live forever if it weren't for his own modifications to become more "human".
However, I don't remember a scene where he saves a girl - at least not from death.